# General Best practice for Event handling (methods)

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

So far I was putting all code that was reaction to event directly into event handling method.
Yesterday I saw somebody somewhere mentioning that only minimum of code should go there.
Is that true ? Or whats the best practice ?

e.g. which one of the examples is better from program-smooth-working point of view, and why, if you may:
Fig1:

```
private void MainForm_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var DropPosX = e.X;   
    string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        CheckFile(s[i])
        LoadFile(s[i]);
        // ..big chunk of code..
    }    
    // ..big chunk of code..    
}
```

Fig2:

```
DoDragDrop(int[] s, int DropPosX)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        CheckFile(s[i])
        LoadFile(s[i]);
        // ..big chunk of code..
    }    
    // ..big chunk of code..
}

private void MainForm_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var DropPosX = e.X;    
    string[] s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);    
    DoDragDrop(s, DropPos);
}
```

..or even
Fig3:

```
int DropPosX;
string[] s;

DoDragDrop()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        CheckFile(s[i])
        LoadFile(s[i]);
        // ...
    }    
    // ...
}

private void MainForm_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    DropPosX = e.X;    
    s = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);    
    DoDragDrop();
}
```

Comment: This question would be better on the [code review stack exchange website](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) I think.

Comment: Sorry maybe I should say I'm not looking for the particular code review. The code is there only as example. -- I can change it to some simpler pseudo-code if you think it would be better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should try to keep a minimum in there.

It can get a bit messy if big chunk of code is say twiddling about with a load of internals (e.g. form controls, but you aim for as much as you can outside of the eventhandler.

All depends on what the big chunk of code is, but even a local private method is better than a huge lump of code in and eventHandler.

If say you were grabbing UI properties to store them in another class. Add a method to it, that takes them as arguments.

If it's a lot of UI stuff, look at a UserControl.

The main reason to do it, is testing UI is a major pain, so the less logic in the UI, the easier the job.

Answer (score 2):

Most event handlers essentially take the following two actions

- Gather relevant data from the event, possible just that the event happened
- Perform an action using the gathered data

It sounds like that person was suggesting that you break up these logical operations into 2 separate methods.  This is sound reasoning but it is also an issue of style.  It doesn't make your program more or less correct to do this.  Although I generally find that code is more testable if you take this approach.

Specific to this sample though.  I would not use instance variables in this case.  The items being dragged and the position are relevant to the `DoDragDrop` method and should be passed as arguments.  If that data needs to be persisted then `DoDragDrop` should be the one to set the instance values.

```
private void MainForm_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    int position = e.X;    
    string[] items = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);    
    DoDragDrop(positon, items);
}
```

Comment: So there is generally nothing wrong with putting a big chunk of code (that may potentially take some time to process) right into the Event handling method ?

Comment: I agree entirely.  There *are* times when using separate methods makes sense, like when some events will "share" code, then putting that code into a separate method that both events can call makes sense.
Breaking it up just for the sake of braking it up sounds like more of a coding style issue to me.

Comment: @Riva those are 2 separate things.  Whether or not your event handler has a big chunk of code is a 100% style issue.  I prefer tight, short methods but it's a style choice.  Long running event handlers are bad though because they degrade the user experience.  If an event handler can't respond promptly it should shift work to a background thread

Comment: @Riva, if you're expecting that your event handling might "potentially take some time to process" and you're concerned about blocking on the thread, then you might need to look into moving that code into a method that can be executed asynchronously.

Comment: I of course agree to prevent code duplication is right,good and needed. That wasn't really scope of my question. -- From that remark I mentioned I got an idea that long code right in Event hander somehow breaks a 'flow' of a program. I understand its not the case now, thanks everybody !

Comment: Big chunk of code is an issue, anywhere. The only time I'd say it doesn't make sense, is if the entire class is very stable, reuse it not expected, and unit tests wouldn't improve your productivity. Not many scenarios where all three of those are true.